# Migration Jersey 2.22.1 to Jersey 2.22.2

Tags: java, jersey, guice, jersey-2.0

Can't to upgrade from the Jersey 2.22.1 version to version 2.22.2.
Hierarchy:
[image]

Dependencies section from build.gradle:

```
def jerseyVersion = '2.22.1'
def hk2Version = '2.4.0-b31'
def giuceVersion = '4.0'

dependencies {
    //javax
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
    //jersey
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:${jerseyVersion}"
    //hk2
    compile "org.glassfish.hk2:guice-bridge:${hk2Version}"
    //guice
    compile "com.google.inject:guice:${giuceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:${giuceVersion}"
}
```

File web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>REST API App</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.core.JerseyGuiceServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Class JerseyGuiceServletContextListener:

```
package com.example.core;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener;

public class JerseyGuiceServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModuleConfig());
    }
}
```

Class JerseyServletModuleConfig:

```
package com.example.core;

import com.google.inject.Scopes;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
import com.example.ws.HeyResource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class JerseyServletModuleConfig extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        Map<String, String> servletContainerParams = new TreeMap<>();
        servletContainerParams.put("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyConfiguration.class.getCanonicalName());
        bind(ServletContainer.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
        filter("/*").through(ServletContainer.class, servletContainerParams);
        bind(HeyResource.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

Class JerseyConfiguration:

```
package com.example.core;

import com.google.inject.Injector;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceBridge;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceIntoHK2Bridge;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    @Inject
    public JerseyConfiguration(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, ServletContext servletContext) {
        packages("com.example.ws");
        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector((Injector) servletContext.getAttribute(Injector.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

At version 2.22.1 Jersey everything works perfectly. As soon as I change the version on 2.22.2 - I got an exception:

> 21-Aug-2016 12:34:12.577 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception
>   starting filter guiceFilter java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.FilterUrlMappingsProviderImpl.getFilterUrlMappings(FilterUrlMappingsProviderImpl.java:66)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:444)

I thought a problem it can be covered in the guice-bridge version. I have replaced from the version 2.4.0-b31 with the version 2.4.0-b34 (which is used for various hk2-dependences from org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server) - hasn't helped.

Link to the class FilterUrlMappingsProviderImpl: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/79d7767be5102f57520cf23900cad3a7ef4230ad/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/FilterUrlMappingsProviderImpl.java

From the link above described class FilterUrlMappingsProviderImpl becomes clear that it is impossible to get an FilterRegistration class object.

What can be the problem exists? What can you advise for her decision? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

---

File web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>REST API App</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.core.JerseyGuiceServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.core.JerseyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Class JerseyServletModuleConfig:

```
package com.example.core;

import com.google.inject.Scopes;
import com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule;
import com.example.ws.HeyResource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class JerseyServletModuleConfig extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        bind(HeyResource.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```